# how to add weight for configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product

in code

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'packsize');
 foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $instance) 
 {
         $myArray[$instance['value']] = $instance['label']; 


 }
 print_r($myArray = $instance['label']);
```

i want to show a packsize retrive from database.

Comment: is `packsize` config attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is;

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute")->loadByCode("catalog_product", 'packsize');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
foreach ($options as $option)
{

    $value = $option['label'];
    echo $value."</br>";
//  $myArray[]=$value; //if you want to save as an array

}
// var_dump($myArray);
```